# Laravel 5.1 eloquent tries to INSERT into DB instead of UPDATE

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I find an existing record like so:

```
$m = new Model();
$value = 1;
                $m->whereField($field)->first(); // Get the model
                if ($m->exists()) { // this is true so I know it's there
                    $m->anotherField = $value
                    $m->save(); // Laravel tries to INSERT vs UPDATE. Why????
                }
```

I know the record can be found because `exists()` is true. Yet I try to save it and Laravel treats it like a brand new record and tries to insert instead of update. What did I do wrong here?

Comment: Is your primary key properly set in your DB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set a variable to the found item

```
$m = $m->whereField($field)->first();
if ($m->exists()) {
$m->anotherField = $value;
$m->save();
}
```

As you have it now, `$m` is only refering to `new Model()`, not to the found item.

Comment: Will check this off in ten minutes. Silly me.

Comment: Happens to the best... :) @JoelJoelBinks

Comment: what is`->exists()`? I thought `$m` maybe either `object` or `null`

Answer (score 1):

You could also do:

```
$m = $m->whereField($field)->firstOrFail();
```

//catch exception... (log or something else)

```
$m->anotherField = $field;
$m->save();
```

> Doing this will let you catch the exception so you can log and display
>   an error page as necessary. To catch the ModelNotFoundException, add
>   some logic to your app/Exceptions/Handler.php file.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent